# Is it possible to export the equations from Mathematica to MATLAB?

Tags: export, matlab

Is it possible to export the output expressions from *Mathematica* computations (e.g., equations) in valid MATLAB syntax?

Comment: Which equations? Can you be more specific on what precisely it is you want to do? one equation? a list of them? Cut and paste? Programmatically export?

Comment: @acl just an equation with Log s exponentials error functions. For example f[x_]=Log[...]+err[..]*Exp[..]. Something that sort. I know there is a command // InputForm but the output has for example $E$ which MATLAB will not understand. I only want to copy paste the equation to MATLAB. Still unclear?

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, but do to the large chat under previous answer I would like to point out that [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/), provides the page where you can find the package, however many struggles with not being able to download it. I had the same problem until I pressed down alt key and pressed the link at the bottom of the page. Might save a bit of time!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is the [`ToMatlab`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) package that will convert *Mathematica* expressions to MATLAB equivalents. For example:

```
<<ToMatlab`
Expand[(x + Log@y)^5] // ToMatlab
(* x.^5+5.*x.^4.*log(y)+10.*x.^3.*log(y).^2+10.*x.^2.*log(y).^3+5.* ...
        x.*log(y).^4+log(y).^5; *)
```

It even conveniently breaks it using `...` and can also convert matrices:

```
RandomInteger[5, {5, 5}] // ToMatlab
(* [5,0,5,3,4;
    5,5,3,0,2;
    1,4,4,4,4;
    0,3,2,5,5;
    4,5,5,1,1]; *)
```

However, it won't convert general definitions or things that don't make sense in MATLAB, such as patterns.

To install the package, extract the `ToMatlab.m` file to

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```