# Telling mathematica to output * instead of space for multiplication, so I can copy as plain text

Tags: output-formatting, symbolic, symbols

I am trying to get some symbolic expressions in Mathematica 
which I would like to paste into my C/MATLAB codes. This can be accomplished 
nicely by selecting the expression and right-clicking to select
`Copy as plain-text`.

However there is one small issue I have.

Consider the simplest possible case for 2 symbols `a` and `b`

```
In[1]:= c = a*b


Out[1]= a b
```

How can I tell Mathematica to produce all its output as `a*b` and not `a b`
Without this, I have to go through the pain of replacing manually all 
spaces in my C/MATLAB codes with the `*` espcecially for long expressions.

Comment: Re: converting to MATLAB friendly expression, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14037/5)

Comment: For MATLAB, use what rm said.  For C, use `CForm`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `*` multiplication operator is rendered in [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputForm.html):

```
c = a b;

c // InputForm
```

> ```
> a*b
> ```

For producing/exporting strings:

```
ExportString[c, "Text"]

ToString[c, InputForm]
```

> ```
> "a*b"
>
> "a*b"
> ```

Comment: or `a b // InputForm` ?

Comment: @cormullion Yes; I guess that might not be apparent to a new user from my answer alone; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the multiplication symbol in `Preferences->Appearance->Numbers->Multiplication`

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do so is use the "Find and Replace" menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), select the blank space between `a` and `b` and replace it with `*` symbol.

It perfectly works for me.