# Explicit multiplication * sign in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, symbols, output

I need to turn my Mathematica output (in string form) to a form that I then need to feed to Maple, and specifically I'd need all multiplications to be marked by * (as opposed to x or, as it happens now, an empty space). How do I get the program to do that?

eg.
2 nu2 b -> 2*nu2*b

(on the other hand, not all spaces correspond to multiplication signs so I can't just replace those..)
Thanks in advance, cheers!
S

Comment: may be `Clear[x, y]; expr = x y; FortranForm[expr]` gives `x*y` then you can give this to Maple. ofcourse you have to test this more to make sure it works for your other expressions.

Comment: related answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25625/telling-mathematica-to-output-instead-of-space-for-multiplication-so-i-can-co?rq=1

Comment: Maple has a package that will convert Mathematica expressions to Maple one.  This is probably the best solution for your problem. http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MmaTranslator/FromMma

Comment: Probably a better duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31804/12