# Is there any way to get Times displayed as $\cdot, *,$ or $\times$ in output form?

Tags: output-formatting, symbols

In the output of *Mathematica*, operators $\cdot$ or * or $\times$ are usally displayed as space; e.g., $x * y$ becomes $x \, y$ in output. Is there any option that can be set to make "space" becomes $\cdot$ or * or $\times$ or preferably $*$?

Comment: You can format your output using `InputForm`, e.g. `x*y // InputForm`

Comment: Thank you so much! I also found similar suggestion at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25625/telling-mathematica-to-output-instead-of-space-for-multiplication-so-i-can-co