# Mathematica-To-MATLAB Dictionary!

Tags: matlab

Is there a dictionary to translate *Mathematica* functions and commands to *MATLAB*?

Comment: [Nasser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) has created an [excellent resource](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/KERNEL2/index.htm) with problems solved both in MMA and MATLAB.

Comment: Worth to check SE tag: [`matlab`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+is%3Aquestion)  too.

Comment: Mathematica core language is strictly more powerful than Matlab core language (note, I don't mean the specialized functionality), so in many or most cases you will find it hard to adequately translate in the *Mathematica* -> Matlab direction. The other direction might be simpler, for the core language at least.

Answer (score 7):

I have found the following page useful for understanding what the equivalent commands are:

http://meng6.net/pages/matlab_mathematica_equivalent_commands/

If you're looking for a package that actually translates between mathematica and matlab, this previous question/answer is a good place to start:

[Is it possible to export the equations from Mathematica to MATLAB?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14035/is-it-possible-to-export-the-equations-from-mathematica-to-matlab?rq=1)

And finally, if you want to call Matlab from Mathematica, there's MATLink, which you can find more info on here:

[Calling MATLAB from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica?rq=1)