# Mathematica to MATLAB special function translation

Tags: special-functions, matlab

I often need to translate results I derive in Mathematica into a MATLAB implementation.  These results sometimes involve special functions (e.g. `Erfc`, `BesselJ`) whose names and argument order do not correspond with those used in MATLAB.

Are there any resources showing such correspondences?

Comment: Can't you just find out the function definitions? So for instance, `Erfc[z]` is the same as `1 - 2/Sqrt[Pi] Integrate[Exp[-t^2], {t, 0, z}]`

Comment: @Feyre: I don't see that directly helps me guess what name I should be looking for in the MATLAB documentation.

Comment: I thought you meant they had no equal, in which case an equivalent statement should be used. Wouldn't this otherwise be better asked at  the Matlab forums?

Comment: @Feyre: this question is only of interest to people who use Mathematica (not all of them, obviously).  There are other positively-rated questions on related topics here (e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44223/mathematica-to-matlab-dictionary)

Comment: @Feyre I don't think so.  The solution requires programming in Mathematica, not MATLAB.  Well, I suppose it could be in principle done pureley in MATLAB too but Mathematica is much better at these sorts of transformations.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  If this is not what you were looking for, let me know and I'll delete the answer.

Comment: The elliptic integrals and elliptic functions are particularly tricky. *Mathematica* uses the parameter convention, while MATLAB uses the modulus convention.

Answer (score 9):

I would first do the necessary transformations manually using a `ReplaceAll`.  Then I would translate the result to MATLAB syntax using tools such as [ToMatlab](http://packagedata.net/index.php/links/search/149/ToMatlab).

For example,

```
trafo = Dispatch@{
   Gamma[a_] :> "gamma"[a],
   Gamma[a_, z_] :> "gamma"[a] (1 - "gammainc"[z, a])
   (* and many more transformations here *)
  }

ToMatlab[ x Sin[x] - Gamma[x,2] /. trafo ]

(*

"(-1).*gamma(x).*(1+(-1).*gammainc(2,x))+x.*sin(x);"

*)
```

You would need to create the replacement table yourself, but this shouldn't be a lot of work.  Finding the corresponding special functions int the documentation is straightforward and the definitions are given on both sides (so you can see if there's a significant difference, such as with the incomplete Γ function above).

Comment: +1 but I would argue that finding, understanding and testing the corresponding special functions (particularly when they take multiple arguments) is non-trivial and that it would be useful to have a reliable list.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a table that I have developed, tested and found to be useful over the years, showing Mathematica functions on the left and their MATLAB equivalents on the right.

```
ArcTan[x,y]                   atan2(y,x)                                                   
BetaRegularized[z,a,b]        betainc(z,a,b)                                               
ExpIntegralE[1,z]             expint(z)                                                    
Gamma[a,z]                    gammainc(z,a,'upper')*gamma(a)                               
GammaRegularized[n,0,x]       gammainc(x,n)                                                
InverseErf[z]                 erfinv(z)                                                    
InverseGammaRegularized[a,s]  None found                                                   
LegendreP[n,x]                first row of: legendre(n,x)                                  
PolyGamma[z]                  psi(z)                                                       
PolyGamma[n,z]                psi(n,z)                                                     
SphericalBesselJ[n,z]         sqrt(pi/(2*z))*besselj(n+1/2,z)*sign(z)                      
SphericalHankelH2[n,z]        sqrt(pi/(2*z))*(besselj(n+1/2,z)-i*bessely(n+1/2,z))*sign(z)
```

I would encourage others to add to and improve this list.

Answer (score 3):

Also, there is a way to convert MeijerG function to Matlab. A ready-to-use Mupad MeijerG function caller for Matlab is available at [Matlab Cental](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32549-meijerg).  The following line need to be modified in [ToMatlab package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) for cell array support:

```
ToMatlabaux[l_List] := "[" <> ToMatlabargs[l] <> "]"
```

Replace this line with:

```
ToMatlabaux[l_List] := 
    If[FreeQ[l,_List,{1,Infinity}],
        "[" <> ToMatlabargs[l] <> "]"(*in case of Matlab vector*),
        "{" <> ToMatlabargs[l] <> "}"(*in case of Matlab cell array*)]
```

Also, for support of empty cells the following line

```
ToMatlabargs[e_] :=
    If[Length[e] === 1, 
        ToMatlabaux[e[[1]]],
        ToMatlabaux[e[[1]]] <> "," <>
            ToMatlabargs[ argslistdrop[e] ] ]
```

need to be replaced with

```
ToMatlabargs[e_] :=
    If[Length[e] === 1, 
        ToMatlabaux[e[[1]]],
        If[Length[e]>0,
        ToMatlabaux[e[[1]]] <> "," <>
            ToMatlabargs[ argslistdrop[e] ],e]]
```

The following lines need to be added to [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) for the case of presence of additional argument `r` in Mathematica `MeijerG`:

```
(*Convert generalized MeijerG to usual MeijerG. MeijerGsubstitute is used in order to avoid potential recursion problem caused by automatic transformation of MeijerG*)
(*  http://functions.wolfram.com/07.35.26.0004.01  *)
ToMatlabaux[MeijerG[{a1__,a2__},{b1__,b2__},z_,r_]]:=ToMatlabaux[MeijerGsubstitute[{a1,a2},{b1,b2},z^(1/r)]]/;Refine[r>=1||r<-1||-Pi*r<Arg[z]<=Pi*r]
(*  http://functions.wolfram.com/07.35.26.0005.01  *)
ToMatlabaux[MeijerG[{a1__,a2__},{b1__,b2__},z_,r_]]:=Module[{n,p,m,q,\[Xi],\[Mu],g,ik},
    n=Length[a1];p=n+Length[a2];m=Length[b1];q=m+Length[b2];\[Xi]=((p+q)/2-m-n)(r-1);
    \[Mu]=Total@b1+Total@b2-(Total@a1+Total@a2)+(p-q)/2+1;
    g[x_]:=Table[(x+ik)/r,{ik,0,r-1}];
    ToMatlabaux[(2 \[Pi])^\[Xi]*r^\[Mu]*MeijerGsubstitute[{Flatten[g/@a1],Flatten[g/@a2]},{Flatten[g/@b1],Flatten[g/@b2]},r^(r(p-q))*z]]]/;Refine[r\[Element]Integers&&r>0]
```

Then MeijerGsubstitute converted to proper function name for call from Matlab:

```
ToMatlabaux[MeijerGsubstitute]:="MeijerG"
```

P.S. ToMatlab package definitely requires an update after 18 years. Updated by me version of ToMatlab is available [here](https://files.fm/u/zx9jgg93). It also includes support for `Piecewise`, `BesselJ`, `BesselY`, `BesselI`, `BesselK`, `HypergeometricPFQ`, `HypergeometricPFQRegularized`.

Updated conversion for `Piecewise` and `If` functions in [my version of ToMatlab](https://files.fm/u/zx9jgg93). Values for all conditions of Piecewise are converted to Matlab cell array of strings. The element of this cell array is extracted by indexing based on the index of condition, that yields True, in array of conditions. Thus, Matlab evaluates only expression, condition of which is satisfied:

```
ToMatlabaux[If[test_, t_, f_]] :="evalin('caller',subsref({"<>"'"<>Assuming[test,ToMatlabaux[t]]<>
    "','"<>Assuming[!test,ToMatlabaux[f]]<>"'"<>
    "},struct('type','{}','subs',{{find("<>ToMatlabaux[{test,True}]<>",1,'first')}})))"

Off[Piecewise::pairs]
ToMatlabaux[Piecewise[z_List, f_.]]:=Module[{lastCondition=Simplify[And@@Not/@z[[All,2]]]},
"evalin('caller',subsref({"<>StringJoin@Map["'"<>Assuming[#[[2]],ToMatlabaux[#[[1]]]]<>"',"&,z]<>"'"<>
    Assuming[lastCondition===False||lastCondition,ToMatlabaux[f]]<>"'"<>
    "},struct('type','{}','subs',{{find("<>ToMatlabaux[Flatten@{z[[All,2]],True}]<>",1,'first')}})))"]
On[Piecewise::pairs]
```

For those, who do not like this ugly/reliable conversion, conversion of `Piecewise` and `If` in terms of products of conditions by corresponding values are left commented in ToMatlab file.