# How can I trans-compile Mathematica into another language?

Tags: export, compile, core-language, interoperability

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of source-to-source compilers to all other languages, if any exist that is.

Comment: I suspect the number of all the cross-compilers would be zero.

Comment: Perhaps something like "MathCode C++" and/or "MathCode F90" would do what you want. These are advertised as "Generates Optimized C++/F90 Code from Mathematica Programs".

Comment: I expect that any such tools will require you to write simplified Mathematica code before they can translate it to another language.

Answer (score 11):

Mathematica has a very large number of builtin functions, most of which would be part of libraries in other languages.  Many of these functions are next to impossible to implement in a compatible way, think e.g. `Integrate`.  Mathematica is also very different from most other languages: it is based on [term rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) and operates with symbols (concepts not found in most other languages).  For this reason **there aren't any *general* source-to-source compilers that can translate Mathematica**.

**There are however tools which can translate a very limited subset of Mathematica.**  These usually require procedural Mathematica code that operates only with machine reals or machine integers.

Let's compile a list of such tools in this community wiki answer.

- Mathematica has builtin tools to generate C code, through `Compile`.  [See the detailed documentation.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Overview.html)
- [MathCode C++](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcode/) and [MathCode F90](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcodef90/) are commercial packages that generate C and Fortran.
- [`CForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CForm.html), [`FortranForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FortranForm.html), [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TeXForm.html), and related functions can translate simple symbolic expressions to other languages.  These don't support arbitrary code, just simple expressions, e.g.: `FortranForm[x^5 + Sin[x] - 6]` $\rightarrow$ `-6 + x**5 + Sin(x)`
- [The ToMatlab package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14037/12) translates expressions to MATLAB (similar to `CForm`, etc.)
- [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/) [includes a tool](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/category.aspx?cid=1408) to translate Mathematica expressions, code snippets or even whole notebooks to Maple expressions, code or worksheets.
- [Mixima](http://ribot.sourceforge.net/) translates Mathematica to [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Feel free to edit this answer and include other tools.