# Vector from Matlab to Mathematica as a function

Tags: functions, matrix, numerical-integration, matlab

I have a 400x1 vector T in Matlab which is a function of another 400x1 vector E. I have these two vectors. I had a few questions :

1. How do I transfer these two vectors to Mathematica
2. I want to write T as a function of E so that I can use NIntegrate to integrate T(E) over E with some tweaking. How do I do that?

Comment: `How do I do that?` you can try http://matlink.org/  package also see this [is-it-possible-to-export-the-equations-from-mathematica-to-matlab](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14035/is-it-possible-to-export-the-equations-from-mathematica-to-matlab) with link  to ToMatlab package you can use. You can also save your matlab data to .mat file, and import it from Mathematica. see [format/MAT.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html)

Comment: But even if I transfer the vector, how do I make it as function of E, so that I can use NIntegrate?

Comment: `even if I transfer the vector, how do I make it as function of E, so that I can use NIntegrate` I do not know how to do this, since description is not clear to me, may be someone else would know and help.

Comment: do you want to make an interpolation of the function `T[E]` from the two vectors and integrate that function? Then you should look at what `Interpolation` can do for you...