# How to change the output of an expression (e.g. a vector) into a form that can be easily copied to Maple?

Tags: output-formatting, maple

I am trying to write the result of the equation of the line passing through points `pA, pB`. My code

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
pB = {3, 6, 7};
u = pB - pA;
pA + u t
```

> {1 + 2 t, 2 + 4 t, 3 + 4 t}

How can I get this result in the form `[1 + 2 t, 2 + 4 t, 3 + 4 t]` which can be easily copied to Maple?

Comment: *Mathematica*'s default convention is to use braces for vectors; why do you need brackets in the output?

Comment: Sometimes, I want to copy the result to Maple.

Comment: Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with the equation of a line.  Don't you see that?  Please write a useful title that will help others find the solution if they have a similar problem, which is only about converting to a Maple format.

Comment: Since Maple afaik can import MatLab-expressions maybe [this old package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14037/764) (ToMatlab.m) is an option?

Comment: I have now rephrased your title to make it (imho) more sensible - if you do not like this, simply roll back.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringReplace[TextString[{a, b, c}], {"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}]
```

[a,b,c]

Answer (score 3):

Even shorter:

```
pA = {1, 2, 3};
pB = {3, 6, 7};
u = pB - pA;
result = pA + u t

mapleForm[ mat_List ] := mat /. List -> "" (* // ToString  see comment by Carl Woll*)

result//mapleForm
```

> [1 + 2 t, 2 + 4 t, 3 + 4 t]

And also:

```
{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}} // mapleForm
```

> [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]

"To see the forest for the trees"* - thanks to b3m2a1 for the helpful comment!

Comment: That's a cute trick. I like it. Even better to hit this at every level: ``result /. List -> ""``

Comment: I would avoid single argument `ToString`, e.g., consider the horrific output from `mapleForm[{1/2, 10^x}]`.